# Cannot hold div when select email from autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below script will create effect fade in and fade out when user hover mouse into login box

```
<script>
$("#login").hover(function() {
    $("#loginForm").slideToggle('500').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
    $("#loginForm").slideToggle('500')
});
</script>
```

but when i want select my email from `<input type="name" name="email_address" />`

[image]

this div `#loginForm` will automatically closed :

[image]

so how to keep this box always show when user select their email address from autocomplete list ?

This issue only happen in browser mozilla firefox.

FYI : change to `<input type="name" name="Email" />` .. this will list your gmail email address

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/r6sQP/)

Comment: May be your autocomplete list outside of the login area

Comment: That autocomplete list is listed by browser. I don't think you can control it. If that's the problem then you can turn off the autocomplete by adding the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to textbox.

Comment: The `div` disappears, even when there is only *one* item in the "autocomplete" list. As soon as the mouse hovers over a list entry it leaves the `div` and the `mouseleave` event of `hover()` is triggered.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran sorry we need autocomplete,  this will make user easy to login ..

Comment: @rusly then keep the login box open after hover and don't close it.

Comment: You need to keep track of whether the dropdown is visible or not; if it is, a click outside would make it disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the drop-down is created by the browser, jQuery thinks the mouse leaves `#login` and will slide up again. To prevent this from happening, you could add an delay to the `slideUp` animation. I created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XdbPV/) to show you what I mean.

```
$("#login").hover(function () {
    $("#loginForm").clearQueue().slideDown(500);
}, function () {
    $("#loginForm").delay(1500).slideUp('500');
});
```

Note the `clearQueue()` method. This will make sure that when the user has selected an email and has its mouse over the element with `#login` it will prevent the `slideUp()` from happening.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise ... But the form will still disappear if the user is a bit slow ;-)

Comment: @cars10 very true, or if the list is long and it takes some time to search for the correct one. I'm sure the OP can tweak this a little. =)

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your HTML and script. I'm keeping the login box open if the textbox is still on `focus`. Also changed `slideToggle` to `slideUp/slideDown` You can try this

**HTML**

```
<form>
<p id="login">     
    <span class="label">Login Here</span>       
    <span id="loginForm">        
        <span class="form-elements">
            <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
            <span class="form-field"><input type="name" name="email_address"  id="email"/></span>                        </span>        
        <span class="form-elements">
            <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
            <span class="form-field"><input type="password" id="pass"/></span>                    </span>        
        <span class="form-elements">
            <span class="submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></span>     
        </span>

    </span>          
</p>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$("#login").hover(function() {
    $("#loginForm").slideDown('500').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
    if($('#email').is(":focus") || $('#pass').is(":focus")) return false;
    $("#loginForm").slideUp('500')
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r6sQP/4/

Comment: This works great, however when the user has an input element selected and clicks somewhere else on the page it will leave the form open.

Comment: Good starting point! But, as Broxzier said, it is a bit "sticky" ... also the check with `$('#pass').is(":focus")` can be taken out since there will not be an autocomplete list for passwords ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better without 500 millisec:

```
$("#loginForm").slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: sorry the result still same. FYI you can try to change to <input type="name" name="Email" /> .. this will list your gmail email address , then you can see its very difficult to select email address and keep this box open

Comment: @rusly ... calling `.slideToggle()` wihtout an argument will work with the same default value of 500 ms.